# How to test styled Material-UI components wrapped in withStyles using react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am trying to create a test with a styled Material-UI component using react-testing-library in typescript. I'm finding it difficult to access the internal functions of the component to mock and assert.

Form.tsx

```
export const styles = ({ palette, spacing }: Theme) => createStyles({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    paper: {
        padding: spacing.unit * 2,
        margin: spacing.unit * 2,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: palette.text.secondary,
    },
    button: {
        margin: spacing.unit * 2,
    }
});

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> { };

export class ExampleForm extends Component<Props, State> {
  async handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    // Handle form Submit
    ...
    if (errors) {
            window.alert('Some Error occurred');
            return;
        }
  }
  // render the form
}
export default withStyles(styles)(ExampleForm);
```

Test.tsx

```
import FormWithStyles from './Form';

it('alerts on submit click', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(window,'alert').mockImplementation(()=>{});
  const spy = jest.spyOn(ActivityCreateStyles,'handleSubmit');
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<FormWithStyles />)
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Submit'));

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

`jest.spyOn` throws the following error `Argument of type '"handleSubmit"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)` probably because ExampleForm in wrapped in withStyles.

I also tried directly importing the `ExampleForm` component and manually assigning the styles, was couldn't do so:

```
import {ExampleForm, styles} from './Form';

it('alerts on submit click', async () => {
  ...

  const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<ActivityCreateForm classes={styles({palette,spacing})} />)

  ...
}
```

Got the  following error: `Type '{ palette: any; spacing: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Theme': shape, breakpoints, direction, mixins, and 4 more.ts(2345)`

I'm finding it difficult to write basic tests in Typescript for `Material-UI` components with `react-testing-library` & `Jest` due to strong typings and wrapped components. Please Guide.

Comment: Can you post a codesandbox demo of the issue?

Answer (score 7):

First of all when you use `render` method of [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) you don't need to worry about using `withStyles` or any wrapper because at the end it renders the component as it could be in the real dom so you can write your tests normally.

Then as far as I can see you are doing the same thing I did when I was starting with *tests* (it means you are going to become good at it ;). You are trying to mock an internal method and that is not the best approach to follow because what you need to do is to test the real method.

So let's image that we have a `Register` users component.

*src/Register.tsx*

```
import ... more cool things
import * as api from './api';

const Register = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (name) {
      api.registerUser({ name });
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField
        id='name'
        name='name'
        label='Name'
        fullWidth
        value={name}
        onChange={handleNameChange}
      />
      <Button data-testid='button' fullWidth type='submit' variant='contained'>
        Save
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The component is pretty simple, its a form with an input and a button. We are using `react hooks` to change the input value and based on that we call or not `api.registerUser` when `handleSubmit` event is fired.

To test the component the first thing we need to do is to *mock* `api.registerUser` method.

*src/__tests__/Register.tsx*

```
import * as api from '../api'

jest.mock('../api')

api.registerUser = jest.fn()
```

This will allow us to see if that method is called or not.

The next thing to do is ... write the tests, in this scenario we can test two things to see if `handleSubmit` is working correctly.

1. Not to call `api.registerUser` if name **is** empty.

```
it('should not call api registerUser method', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Register />)
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button'))
  expect(api.registerUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
})
```

2. Call `api.registerUser` if name **is not** empty.

```
it('should call api registerUser method', () => {
  const { getByLabelText, getByTestId } = render(<Register />)

  fireEvent.change(getByLabelText('Name'), { target: { value: 'Steve Jobs' }})

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button'))
  expect(api.registerUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

In this last test implicitly we are testing `handleNameChange` too because we are changing the name :) so `name` is not going to be empty and `registerUser` is going to be called.

The example with **withStyles** and **typescript** is in this [repo](https://github.com/arkgast/testing-react-form). 
The demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-react-form-f4msn).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `enzyme` with [Full DOM Rendering](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html)?
You can use `simulate` method to simulate events on mounted components.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={`clicks-${count}`}>
          {count} clicks
        </div>
        <a href="url" onClick={() => { this.setState({ count: count + 1 }); }}>
          Increment
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const wrapper = mount(<Foo />);

expect(wrapper.find('.clicks-0').length).to.equal(1);
wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
expect(wrapper.find('.clicks-1').length).to.equal(1);
```

Comment: I wish to use `react-testing-library` by @kentcdodds as it is a non-bloated library which works in a way my user intends to use the application. I suppose I could switch to `enzyme` if there is no other option, but I don't see any reason why it just shouldn't be possible to test `Material-UI` with `react-testing-library`.

Comment: Can that error happen because `handleSubmit` method is `async`? Have you tried it without `async/await`?

Comment: When testing with a component library I look at the recommendations from that library: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/test#writing-tests `For all unit tests, please use the shallow renderer from enzyme unless the Component being tested requires a DOM. Here's a small shallow rendered test to get you started.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use unwrap to unwrap the wrapped styled component then test it

```
import { unwrap } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';
import {ExampleForm, styles} from './Form';

it('alerts on submit click', async () => {
  ...
const unwrapped = unwrap(ExampleForm);
    ...
}
```

Then you can do he required testing on the unwrapped object